# Images, Stylesheets and scripts not loading on zend website

Tags: zend-framework

I have migrated a Zend (Version 1.9.3) website to another server and now I can only get the home page with no scripts or stylesheets and images loaded.

I noticed that most files use the baseUrl for links like
$this->baseUrl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

However if I manually set the baseUrl inside the default.php file some stylesheets are loaded and some are not using
$this->baseUrl = '/ctm/example.com/public/';

My virtual host points to:
/home/e-smith/files/ibays/ctm/html

Does this anything to do with how my virtual host was setup or pointing to? Any help Im still new to zend framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Virtual Host's Directory should actually be pointing to:

```
<Directory "/home/ctm/example.com/public/">
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```